# How can i remove or correct the spelling mistakes in excel file or text file using nltk or python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, nltk, spell-checking

Actually i have a excel file and i have to correct the spelling of words in each column of that file.
I have also a tab delimited file i want also correct theirs spells. Gramerly correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [autocorrect](https://pypi.org/project/autocorrect/) library to do so.

```
from autocorrect import spell 
print spell(u'luve')
print spell(u'hvte')
```

Output:

```
love
hate
```